Issue with managing env values
Hope everyone is doing well. I am trying to make a Multi-tenency web application for a university project of mine. But I am facing issues in managing a env value.
In my ormconfig file, I have written the following:
ormconfig.ts:
import { PostgresConnectionOptions } from 'typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresConnectionOptions';
import { Auth } from 'src/entities/auth.entity';

const config: PostgresConnectionOptions = {
  type: 'postgres',
  database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'root',
  entities: [Auth],
  synchronize: true,
};

export default config;

Everytime I provide a valid login credentials, it says that Invalid Credentials. My login information is totally corrent. Here is the error:
[Nest] 11916  - 05/14/2024, 3:20:52 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Invalid Credentials on 54
Error: Invalid Credentials on 54
    at AuthService.logIn (F:\University\10th Semesteer\Course\Adv Webtech\Project\hms-backend-org\src\auth\auth.service.ts:54:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at F:\University\10th Semesteer\Course\Adv Webtech\Project\hms-backend-org\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-execution-context.js:46:28
    at F:\University\10th Semesteer\Course\Adv Webtech\Project\hms-backend-org\node_modules\@nestjs\core\router\router-proxy.js:9:17

To verify that the issue is no issue connecting with the database, I have manually set the database name to the existing db i have already for test purpose.
database: 'HSM03464'
Using the same credentials, the application properly logged in without any error.

I thought that the process.env.DATABASE_NAME value is not setting properly, but as I have used console.log, it says the database name accordingly but still the application is not loggin in properly and keeps saying the same error.
I have tried assigning the value of process.env.DATABASE_NAME using a middleware and even directly using fetch from the frontend. No luck.

I hope that someone can shed some light on this matter and help me in making an awesome project. TIA!

did you try to add import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

In that case can you clarify me in a matter? Do i need to create a .env file at the root of my project? Cause i am assuming the whole time that process.env is a stort of secured global variable which can store data in some sort if way in the nestjs project. If I use the package that you said, do i need to change any of my code according to the coding pattern for the package?

yeah, you should create your .env in the project, if not, Node will take the global environment, and you're global environment doesn't have DATABASE_NAME
